# Using strapi V4 graphql and nextjs - filters not work

Tags: javascript, next.js, graphql, strapi

I´m using strapi V4 with the graphql extension. When i´m use filters with variables in the graphql Playground there are no problems.

```
query getOrdersFilterList($searchstring: String!) {
orders(filters: { customer: { contains: $searchstring } }) {
    data {
      attributes {
        number
        customer
        name
        article
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query Variables:

```
    {
  "searchstring": "zi"
}
```

When i use filters with Postman no problems.

```
query getOrdersFilterList($searchstring: String) {
    orders(filters: {customer: { containsi:  $searchstring}}) {
        data {
            attributes {
                number
                customer
                name
                article
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Graphql Variables :

```
{
    "searchstring": "zi"
}
```

The result is like expected:

```
{
   "data": {
       "orders": {
           "data": [
               {
                   "attributes": {
                       "number": "30072",
                       "customer": "Stauder Zimmerei",
                       "name": "Hagmann Habsburgerstr.",
                       "article": "Stahlteile "
                   }
               },
               {
                   "attributes": {
                       "number": "22-02-015 A",
                       "customer": "Ziebarth Wolfgang",
                       "name": "Austr. 1 a",
                       "article": "Aussengeländer "
                   }
               },
               {
                   "attributes": {
                       "number": "30013",
                       "customer": "Ziser",
                       "name": "Bürklinstraße 7, Lahr",
                       "article": "Geländer mit Mlichglas "
                   }
               }
           ]
       }
   }
}
```

Now my nextjs app code:

```
export const getOrdersFilterList = async (page, pageSize, searchstring) => {
   const data = await client.query({
    query: gql`
    query getOrdersFilterList($searchstring: String) {
    orders(filters: {customer: { contains:  $searchstring}}){
          data {
          attributes {
            number
            customer 
            name
            article
          }
        }
      }
    }`,
        variables: {searchstring}
  })
```

Variables same as above ( searchstring come from the call of the function )

```
{
    "searchstring": "zi"
}
```

this is what i get on the console (Firefox):
" Object { data: {…}, loading: false, networkStatus: 7 } "

I spend days to search. I can´t find a clue

Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved !
The Problem was the Variable

```
{
    "searchstring": "zi"
}
```

In every Tutorial or example i find it like above.
But the only thing your Variable must contain is

```
zi
```

let´s explain in the code :

```
export const getOrdersFilterList = async () => {
  // this is the variable
  const searchstring = "zi"
  // thats all
  const data = await client.query({
    query: gql`
    query getOrdersFilterList($searchstring: String) {
    orders(filters: {customer: { containsi:  $searchstring}}){
          data {
          attributes {
            number
            customer 
            name
            article
          }
        }
      }
    }`,
        variables: {searchstring}
  })
```